# WMQ/JMS Holding back commit until certain event

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

in my application I asynchronously get messages from MQ queue in a transacted session (I have a message listener registered to my consumer that calls commit after sending the message for processing) but I need not to commit (not to take the message off the queue) before another thread finishes and updates information. Is there a good, standard solution to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not update information from message listener thread itself? If the update fails, you rollback else commit.

Comment: Try using java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier..

Comment: Btw I wouldn't call CyclicBarrier as a "standard" way. Mixing asynchronous consumer and multithreading is somewhat failure-be-design situation as asynchronous consumers are, you know, asynchronous; so if you need them synchronized to something else why do you use them in the first place? If you are able to rewrite code singlethreadly you should do it (multithreaded transactions be damed!). If not use CyclicBarrier or CountingSemaphore..